# How to change WPF CollectionViewGroup type to custom type and use it in ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

How can override the type of View property to my custom type.
My CustomGroupListCollectionView type adds extra property to the Groups property.
During runtime when i observe the type of View property is ListCollectionView, i want to change this to CustomGroupListCollectionView.

```
public class CollectionViewSourceCustom : CollectionViewSource
{
    public new  CustomGroupListCollectionView View { get; set; }
}

public class CustomGroupListCollectionView : ListCollectionView
{
    private readonly CustomGroup _allGroup;

    public CustomGroupListCollectionView(IList list)
        : base(list)
    {
        _allGroup = new CustomGroup("All");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            _allGroup.AddItem(item);
        }
    }

    public override ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> Groups
    {
        get
        {
            var group = new ObservableCollection<object>(base.Groups.ToList());
            group.Add(_allGroup);
            return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>(group);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomGroup : CollectionViewGroup
{
    public CustomGroup(object name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

    public void AddItem(object item)
    {
        ProtectedItems.Add(item);
    }

    public override bool IsBottomLevel
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    bool _IsChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _IsChecked; }
        set { _IsChecked = value; }
    }
    Visibility _CheckBoxVisibility;
    public Visibility CheckBoxVisibility
    {
        get { return _CheckBoxVisibility; }
        set { _CheckBoxVisibility = value; }
    }

    bool _IsExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _IsExpanded; }
        set { _IsExpanded = value; }
    }
    Visibility _ExpanderVisibility;
    public Visibility ExpanderVisibility
    {
        get { return _ExpanderVisibility; }
        set { _ExpanderVisibility = value; }
    }

    Visibility _ImageVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility ImageVisibility
    {
        get { return _ImageVisibility; }
        set { _ImageVisibility = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CollectionViewSource has a CollectionViewType property, which you can use to determine the type of CollectionView the CollectionViewSource returns, like

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="source" CollectionViewType="{x:Type my:CustomGroupListCollectionView}" Source="{Binding MyData}"/>
```

As you see, you don't even have to create a new CollectionViewSource class.

Comment: Gives me this error at runtime 'CollectionViewType property can only be set during initialization' while assigning the new type this.GroupByView.CollectionViewType = typeof(CustomGroupListCollectionView);

Comment: This message means that you can only set the CollectionViewType property either in XAML or before the Initialized event fires; that would be in the constructor before the call to initializecomponent.

Answer (score 2):

If you still persist on using your way I would suggest this code:

```
public class CollectionViewSourceCustom : CollectionViewSource
{
    public CollectionViewSourceCustom()
        : base()
    {
        ((ISupportInitialize)this).BeginInit();

        this.CollectionViewType = typeof(CustomGroupListCollectionView);

        ((ISupportInitialize)this).EndInit();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.